# NestJS: Receive form-data in Guards?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, multer, nestjs

I'm looking to see form-data in my NestJS Guards. I've [followed the tutorial](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#authorization-guard), however, I'm not seeing the request body for my form-data input. I do see the body once I access a route within my controller, however.

Here's some code snippets of what I'm working with:

```
module.ts


...

@Module({
  imports: [
    MulterModule.register({
      limits: { fileSize: MULTER_UPLOAD_FILESIZE_BYTES },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [MainController],
  providers: [
    MainService,
    AuthGuard,
  ],
})
...
```

```
AuthGuard.ts


import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest(); // body is empty if form-data is used
    return true;
  }
}
```

```
MainController.ts


...

@Post("/upload")
@UseInterceptors(AnyFilesInterceptor())
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  async upload(
    @Body() body: UploadDTO,
    @UploadedFiles() files: any[]
  ): Promise<any> {
    console.log(body) // works as expected, whether form-data is used or not
    ...
  }
...
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Guards run before Interceptors. Have you tried using a custom middleware?

Answer (score 4):

NestJS guards are always executed before any middleware. You can use multer manually on the request object you get from the context.

```
import * as multer from 'multer'
...
async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
  const request: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  const postMulterRequest = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    multer().any()(request, {}, function(err) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(request);
    });
  });
  // postMulterRequest has a completed body
  return true;
}
```

If you want to use the @UploadedFiles decorator, you need to clone the request object before modifying it in your guard.

Of course you need to have installed the multer module with:

```
npm install multer
```

Comment: could you elaborate on `you need to clone the request object before modifying it in your guard` this part? How do you cloine the req obj?>

Comment: I tried to clone my object via lodash (deepClone) and faced with issue :/ My body was empty but with original object all works fine.

Comment: I tried cloning the request object but the thread seems just stuck. Anyone has solve this?

Comment: If anyone stumbled upon this issue check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72179559/10660967

Comment: As @xsephtion I've tried to clone the request but using lodash cloning the thread gets stuck. Using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request))` gives a `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. Any solution for this?

Comment: @Postie check the link that I've posted :)

Comment: @xsephtion I did check what you are doing. However (and I know this is a bad idea but it's the only way I know of now) I need to use it with authentication so I want to use a guard. For now I'm just handling the authentication logic inside the controller.

Comment: NestJS guards are always executed AFTER all middleware https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

Comment: @murtuzaali_surti but the parsing happens inside the interceptors, which executes AFTER guards. https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#summary

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution in-case it helps other devs dealing with the same issue.

To start, I created a middleware to handle the conversion of the multipart form data request. You could also inline this in to your guard if you only have one or two. Much of this code is plagiarised from the source code, and is not fully tested:

```js
const multerExceptions = {
    LIMIT_PART_COUNT: 'Too many parts',
    LIMIT_FILE_SIZE: 'File too large',
    LIMIT_FILE_COUNT: 'Too many files',
    LIMIT_FIELD_KEY: 'Field name too long',
    LIMIT_FIELD_VALUE: 'Field value too long',
    LIMIT_FIELD_COUNT: 'Too many fields',
    LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE: 'Unexpected field',
}

function transformException(error: Error | undefined) {
    if (!error || error instanceof HttpException) {
        return error
    }
    switch (error.message) {
        case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FILE_SIZE:
            return new PayloadTooLargeException(error.message)
        case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FILE_COUNT:
        case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FIELD_KEY:
        case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FIELD_VALUE:
        case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FIELD_COUNT:
        case multerExceptions.LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE:
        case multerExceptions.LIMIT_PART_COUNT:
            return new BadRequestException(error.message)
    }
    return error
}

@Injectable()
export class MultipartMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        // Read multipart form data request
        // Multer modifies the request object
        await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            multer().any()(req, res, (err: any) => {
                if (err) {
                    const error = transformException(err)
                    return reject(error)
                }
                resolve()
            })
        })

        next()
    }
}
```

Then, I applied the middleware conditionally to any routes which accept multipart form data:

```js
@Module({
    controllers: [ExampleController],
    imports: [...],
    providers: [ExampleService],
})
export class ExampleModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(MultipartMiddleware).forRoutes({
            path: 'example/upload',
            method: RequestMethod.POST,
        })
    }
}
```

Finally, to get the uploaded files, you can reference `req.files`:

```js
@Controller('example')
export class ExampleController {
    @Post('upload')
    upload(@Req() req: Request) {
        const files = req.files;
    }
}
```

I expanded this in my own codebase with some additional supporting decorators:

```js
export const UploadedAttachment = createParamDecorator(
    (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
        const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()
        return request.files?.[0]
    }
)

export const UploadedAttachments = createParamDecorator(
    (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
        const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()
        return request.files
    }
)
```

Which ends up looking like:

```js
@Controller('example')
export class ExampleController {
    @Post('upload')
    upload(@UploadedAttachments() files: Express.Multer.File[]) {
        ...
    }
}
```