# Nest.js - Pass data from Guard to @UploadFile

Tags: nestjs

Reference Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61407264/8518207

The author of the above answer mentions you can `clone the request object before modifying it in your guard`.

How can this be done?

My Goal: Guard will basically verify if the auth token is valid before proceeding to doing anything in the controller such as call `FileInterceptor` or print those console logs. if token is guard is verified, the FileInterceptor should be used to extract the file from the request.

Example Code:

```
  @Put(':uid')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './.tmp',
        filename: editFileName,
      }),
      fileFilter: fileFilter,
    }),
  )

  public async update(
    @Req() req,
    @UploadedFile() file,
  ) {
    this.logger.log('update')
    console.log('in controller')
    console.log('req', req)
    console.log('file', file)
  }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse()
    const postMulterRequest: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const multerReponse = multer().any()

      multerReponse(request, response, err => {
        const user_uid = request.body.user_uid
        if (err) reject(err)
        resolve(request)
      })
    })
    if (request) {

      // some validations happen here....

      request.body = postMulterRequest.body
      request.user = await this.validateToken(request.headers.cookie, user_uid)

      return true
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
```