# How to clone Request in nestjs guard?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, nestjs, multer

I need to get request params from form-data request in nest guard，so I use multer in my guard

```
async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    const postMulterRequest: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      multer().any()(request, {}, function(err) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(request);
      });
    });
}
```

and I also need to get files and request data in controller

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('filedata'))
  async UploadedFile(@UploadedFile() file, @Body() body, @Request() req): Promise<ImgInfo> {}
```

when I did not use multer, it works. But after using multer, it performs:
`file: undefined, body:{}`
I can get file from the req but can not get other params

**I want to know how can I get the from form-data request in guard without modifying the original request?**

reference：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294070/nestjs-receive-form-data-in-guards/61407264#61407264

Comment: Hi! Have you find answer on this one?

Comment: I'm wondering the same