# Intercepting in Multer Mutates Request? (NestJS)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, multer, interceptor

Does multer mutates any request that has given to it? I'm currently trying to intercept the request to add this in logs.

But whenever I try to execute this code first:

```
        const newReq = cloneDeep(request); // lodash cloneDeep
        const newRes = cloneDeep(response); 
        const postMulterRequest: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const multerReponse = multer().any()
    
          multerReponse(request, newRes, err => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            resolve(request)
          })
        })
        files = postMulterRequest?.files;
```

The `@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))` becomes undefined.

I have already seen the problem, it seems like the `multerReponse(request, newRes, err => {` mutates the request. But I don't know what the other approach I can do to fix this. (I tried JSON Serialization, Object.assign, cloneDeep, but none of those worked)

I have tried adding `newReq` and `newRes` (cloned object) to multerResponse at first it worked. But at the second time, the thread only hangs up, and doesn't proceed to next steps. Or the `multerReponse(request, newRes, err => {` doesn't return anything.

The whole code looks like this and used globally (some parts of here were redacted/removed; but the main logic is still the same) :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuditingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Auditing.name)
    private readonly AuditingModel: Model<Auditing>,
  ) {}

  async intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler,
  ): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    const { headers, method, ip, route, query, body } = request;
    let bodyParam = Object.assign({}, body),
      files: any;
    const newReq = cloneDeep(request); // lodash cloneDeep
    const newRes = cloneDeep(response);
    const postMulterRequest: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const multerReponse = multer().any();
      multerReponse(newReq, newRes, (err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(newReq);
      });
    });
    files = postMulterRequest?.files;

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(() =>
        this.AuditingModel.create({
          request: {
            query,
            bodyParam,
            files,
          },
          timeAccessed: new Date().toISOString(),
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Summary of what I need to do here is I need to intercept and log the file in our DB before it gets processed in the method/endpoint that uses `@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))`.

Comment: I've seen the similar problem but no solution. Reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294070/nestjs-receive-form-data-in-guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this by intercepting the request using the

> @Req() req

and creating a method to handle the files that was intercepted inside the FileInterceptor decorator.

Code Example:

```
// create logs service first to handle your queries
createLogs(file, req){
   // do what you need to do with the file, and req here
   const { filename } = file;
   const { ip } = req
   ....

}


// main service
   // inject the service first

constructor(@Inject(LogsService) private logsService: LogsService)
uploadHandler(file, req){
   this.logsService.createLogs(file, req)
   // proceed with the next steps
   .... 
}

// controller
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
testFunction(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,, @Req req){
    return this.serviceNameHere.uploadHandler(file, req);
}
```